# Meteor 1.8.1 SSL double connecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, meteor, meteor-accounts

I have a localhost server (Windows 10 Pro x64 build 1903) that is being used for development before being pushed to production (Galaxy). For authentication through Facebook or Google, it requires to have HTTPS. I installed Nourharidy Meteor SSL over port 443 with Force-HTTPS. After starting up Meteor, it will throw this error:

```
W20191112-15:12:29.358(2)? (STDERR)
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\nourharidy_ssl\0.2.2\npm\node_modules\http-proxy\lib\http-proxy\index.js:119
W20191112-15:12:30.711(2)? (STDERR)     throw err;
W20191112-15:12:30.718(2)? (STDERR)     ^
W20191112-15:12:30.719(2)? (STDERR) 
W20191112-15:12:30.721(2)? (STDERR) Error: socket hang up
W20191112-15:12:30.765(2)? (STDERR)     at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:342:15)
W20191112-15:12:30.767(2)? (STDERR)     at Socket.socketCloseListener (_http_client.js:377:23)
W20191112-15:12:30.768(2)? (STDERR)     at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
W20191112-15:12:30.773(2)? (STDERR)     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
W20191112-15:12:30.797(2)? (STDERR)     at TCP._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:561:12)
```

When I check Netstat, it shows that NodeJS is using IPv4 and IPv6. I'm wondering if that is what is causing it?

After the first time, it stops and recompiles, and then it goes through. I think the issue is related to NodeJS 8.12, but I looked at the GitHub, and it seems to be fixed in NodeJS 10, as seen here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/29715. Until Meteor gets up there, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Updated to Meteor 1.8.3 and the issue has disappeared.